# how to conditionally return to form with messagebox yes/no

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm not sure how to handle returning to the form after this checkbox value check.  My intention is to identify that two checkboxes were not selected and give the user a chance to go back to the form and choose if they click no on a messagebox. If they click yes, then proceed.  What is the proper way to handle?

```
 private void btnConfirmCheckin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string activity_log_id = txtactivity_log_id.Text;
            string CheckInTime = txtCheckInTime.Text;
            bool @bm = checkBoxBM.Checked;
            bool @ur = checkBoxUr.Checked;
            string activity_id = comboactivity_id.SelectedValue.ToString();

            if (checkBoxBM.Checked == false && checkBoxUr.Checked == false)
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Nothing was selected for this outing.  Continue?", "Business Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    //user correctly chose nothing, wants to continue
                    return;
                }
                else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    //user made mistake, return to form and make a selection
                    
                }
            }


            AssignRescueActivity ara = new AssignRescueActivity();
            ara.SaveCheckin(activity_log_id, CheckInTime, bm, ur, activity_id);
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: if validation fields are mandatory, why not keep user in that ui until validating passed?

Comment: If the user made a mistake, and clicked the “No” button on the dialog… Then … DON’T call … `this.Close` … The current code is closing the form if the user clicks “No” in the dialog.

Comment: @LeiYang, if that is the better way, I would do it if I knew how.  I should have mentioned I am not a c# developer.

Comment: when you close messagebox, you should be still at the original Form, right?

Comment: @LeiYang, when user clicks no, they should be returned to the form.  when they click yes, the form should save and close.